# Is there a way/browser plug-in available that can turn off and on Airplane Mode without using the physical button?

Tags: airplane-mode

I want to quickly turn off and on data on my S3 while I read long articles on the web which I noticed saves a lot of battery.  But the physical button is too worn off already and I don't want to exit whatever I'm doing to off the data.  Is there a way to off and on Airplane Mode from the status bar or a plug-in I can install in the Chrome browser?

OS: 4.1.1
Phone: Samsung Galaxy S3

Comment: Reconnecting to a Wi-Fi or 3G network uses more power than leaving it idle for several minutes. Although having it off saves power, don't think you can save more power by turning it off for a few minutes at a tine.

Comment: I tested it.  For now something is draining my battery at the rate of 1% a minute and I find when I turn the data off it drains at like 1% every 6 per minute.

Comment: That's suspiciously much. It sounds more like an app keeping the CPU hot than the data connection itself. If you go into Settings → Battery, are there any apps using a lot?

Comment: I've been trying to figure that out.  Right now, it says Chrome is using the most at 40%.  But why does my phone last longer with the data off if it's the CPU?  Temp is 31 degrees in Celsius.

Comment: It could be that Chrome is doing something CPU-intensive, but only while an internet connection is available: turning data off stops it running. 40% is a lot, but I can't think what it might be doing. Try force-stopping it and clearing its cache (from Settings → Applications Manager) and see if that helps.

Comment: Actually, if it's while you're using Chrome, it may be its precaching. In Chrome, go to Settings → Bandwidth management → Preload web pages and set it to **Never**, and see if that helps.

Comment: Temp of the battery that is....

Comment: Chrome wasn't pre-caching at all and I cleared the cache but it doesn't seem to make much difference.  What does the cache do?

Answer (score 2):

Several, I'm sure. There's the simple [Airplane Mode Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.guywmustang.airplanewidget) for one. Then there's the way more complicated, but ***way*** more powerful [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) for another (since it's capable of creating widgets to execute any of the tasks you define).

Oh, wait, the title said widget, but the question says status bar. On my S3 (also on 4.1.1), I can pull down the notifications, slide the power switches to the left a little bit, and there's the switch for Airplane mode. Does that work on yours?

If you haven't got the Airplane mode switch in your status bar, then the easiest solution would probably be [SwipePad](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.conduction.swipepad.android) with a shortcut (not widget) to toggle Airplane Mode. This is the combination I use to turn on my LED flashlight (with [TeslaLED](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.flashlight)). The reason you want a shortcut instead of a widget is because it saves you steps. If [Airplane Mode Switch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.vanini.ottavio.android.utility) does indeed use a shortcut instead of a widget, then you're golden without having spent a dime. If it doesn't, then you can still buy the [WidgetPad](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.calciumion.swipepad.addons.widgetpad) add on for SwipePad and use a widget, or buy Tasker and use it to create a shortcut which toggles airplane mode.

Comment: When you pull down the notifications bar, there's a row of buttons at the top: **Wi-Fi**, **GPS**, **Sound**, **Screen rotation**, &c. You can flick them to the left to see more, but there's no Airplane mode switch on my S3 (4.1.2).

Comment: That's interesting @DanHulme. Which country are you in and which carrier are you on? I'm in the US on AT&T, with 4.1.1 and I do have airplane mode in the status bar switches. I think Samsung gives you the ability to choose the switches in their 4.2 update, but who knows when or if the carriers will push that out.

Comment: The UK, but with a German unlocked build of the phone. I know I used to have different buttons until it OTA'ed, but can't remember whether Airplane mode was among them.

Comment: "Airplane mode switch" has not been updated for years so I'm worried it might be unstable with the newer systems.

Comment: I suspect "Airplane Mode Switch" is so simple, there hasn't been any need to update it, @verve. In any case, it worked just fine on my S3 when I tried it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

One of the features of [Battery Widget Reborn](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hubalek.android.apps.reborn.pro)'s notification is buttons to toggle WiFi, Bluetooth, Sync, Mobile Data, and Airplane mode. I got it for the battery usage analysis, but this extra feature is a really nice touch. Now I only need pull down my notification shade to access these important toggles. (Although, yes, with the new settings panel in Jelly Bean I don't really need it. It's a couple less taps.)

[image: developer's screen shot]